# Mouseover tooltips on Raphael SVG paths

Tags: jquery, svg, raphael

I use Raphael Sketchpad (a library under Raphael) to draw SVG paths.
I want to fire events when a mouse over event occours on the paths, but I tried all examples I could find on this topic with no help, the mouse over event is not firing when I hit a path element, hovever I can easily attach a mouse over event listener to the SVG container, but that is not what I want to achieve.

Below is a snippet of the rendered HTML

```
        <div id="sketchpad" style="-moz-user-select: text;">
            <div class="box" id="demo-mouse" style="-moz-user-select: text;">

                <div style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); cursor: crosshair; -moz-user-select: text;" id="canvas">
<svg height="750" version="1.1" width="1200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; -moz-user-select: text;"><desc>Created with Raphaël 2.1.0</desc><defs/>
<path style="stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round;" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M287,226L311,259L337,280L349,287L359,294L378,309L396,318L399,320L405,323L406,325L408,328L409,328L410,329L411,329L413,326L414,320L416,296L418,280L418,267L420,233L423,220L427,208L430,186L432,177L432,174L432,160L432,157L432,150L430,139L429,134L429,129" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" text-anchor="" stroke-linejoin="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"/>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

The JS code, placed inside a document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#sketchpad path").on("mouseover", function() {
   console.log("HIT"); // Nothing happens
})
});
```

Any suggestions?

My goal is to have a toolbar displayed on the mouse position when the mouse hits a path (like QTip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$("#sketchpad").on("mouseover", "path", function() {
   console.log("HIT");
})
```

And even better - use Raphael's native method **Element.mouseover** http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.mouseover

Comment: "path" does not exist yet even on "$(document).ready". Raphael adds it later. So in such cases you have to point jQuery to already existing parent object - #sketchpad. And then define child object (which will be added later) in parameters of .on method. Read jquery docs for .on method: http://api.jquery.com/on/